# how to use npm package javascript inside react component

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use rc-calender in react.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-calendar
I need to use css for this package.
I am trying to use this as follows.

```
require('rc-calendar/assets/bootstrap.css');
```

But it is giving me

> **ParseError**: Unexpected token.

I am getting similar error for all other css(from other npm packages).

Any idea how to use these CSS.

Comment: Well, CSS is not JavaScript, so you cannot simply `require` it. You can directly reference it in your HTML.

Comment: Actually I was following http://react-component.github.io/calendar/examples/picker.html tutorial. Not sure how it working here

Comment: What build tool are you using? They all have plugins to require in different resources like css, but it depends on the build tool..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using webpack. Is require('rc-calendar') alone loading ?

Check that first maybe. Then check the path in your npm-module maybe you have a newest version of the module and the path in the tutorial you followed is wrong.

hope it helps